# Element not visible - Selenium - Java Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to fill a form on a website and I am unable to find the element that is listed in the code.

My code:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div/div/input[1]")));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div/div/input[1]")).sendKeys("TEST");
```

Relative website code:

```
<body>
   <div id="pf_form" class="pf_formcontainer">
   <form id="PF_1" class="form formBoxShadow" style="height: 1600px; width: 
      1800px; display: block; left: 0px; top: 30px;">
   <div id="PF_4Container" class="PageContainer" style="left:0px;top:0px;z-
      index:0;position:absolute">
   <div id="PF_4" class="page" tabindex="" name="PF_4" style="width: 1800px; 
      height: 1600px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: block;">
   <input id="PF_5" class="textinput" name="PF_5" maxlength="99" value="" 
      onclick="return false;" style="left: 169px; top: 107px; z-index: 6; height: 
      18px; line-height: 18px; width: 206px; display: block;" type="text">
   ...
```

I've tried to change to the frame PF_4 and PF_4Container, no luck there. I've tried to find it by ID and other means but this one is kicking my butt.

The form is publicly visible here http://app.perfectforms.com/PresentationServer/Form.aspx/Play/FdjigAcE?f=FdjigAcE

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  I've been trying to resolve this for weeks now.

Comment: What error do you get when you use id? driver.findElement(By.id('PF_5')). I do not see any iframes...

Comment: Try if your xpath path is correct using the evaluate path from the console -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  It seems that it cannot find the element.  Feel free to run it on the url.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your HTMl elements with ids already why using xpath?
Simply use:

```
WebDriverWait wait = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30));
WebElement input = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("PF_5")));
input.sendKeys("tests tests");
```

Comment: Thanks Christian!  I added this but the error that is returned is:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible